# How sensitive is DeviceOrientation when browsing the web on Mobile in a handheld context

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, device-orientation

I'd like to determine the chances or prospects of reading a mobile device's orientation using the `DeviceOrientation` Javascript API (*not* `orientationchange`) when loading a web page.

Unless I am mistaken, the [W3C specs](http://w3c.github.io/deviceorientation/spec-source-orientation.html) indicate the `DeviceOrientation` properties can only be read during an event trigger. i.e. The initial states are not exposed if the device is not moving at all.

If so, is `DeviceOrientation` sensitive enough to read a value in most common cases where the device is held by hand(s), while the user wait for a page load, assuming very subtle hand/motion tilts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing on actual devices, I am noticing that the device orientation is quite sensitive. For my initial use case anyway. It's sensitive enough that it almost always fire, reporting `alpha`, `beta` and `gamma` value that are not all 0 when using any mobile browser (phone or tablet) that support the DeviceOrientation API, not matter how you use it (even if it sits on a table).

The drawback is that the `ondeviceorientation` event only fires after `window.load` on Webkit/Blink. Or about 25ms to 100ms after the window `load` event, varying upon browsers and devices. While Firefox fires the event early at the `interactive` state of the document before `DOMContentLoaded`.

So it seems impossible to start rendering a web page in the context of the *initial* device's rotation for lack of early detection capabilities. That's a significant flaw of the current DeviceOrientation API.